# Increasing time resolution of BOOST::progress timer

Tags: c++, boost

BOOST::progress_timer is a very useful class to measure the running time of a function. However, the default implementation of progress_timer is not accurate enough and a possible way of increasing time resolution is to reconstruct a new class as the following codes show:

```
#include <boost/progress.hpp>
#include <boost/static_assert.hpp>

template<int N=2>
class new_progress_timer:public boost::timer
{
public:
    new_progress_timer(std::ostream &os=std::cout):m_os(os)
    {
        BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(N>=0 &&N<=10);
    }
    ~new_progress_timer(void)
    {
        try
        {
            std::istream::fmtflags old_flags =
                m_os.setf(std::istream::fixed,std::istream::floatfield);
            std::streamsize old_prec = m_os.precision(N);
            m_os<<elapsed()<<"s\n"
                <<std::endl;

            m_os.flags(old_flags);
            m_os.precison(old_prec);

        }
        catch(...)
        {
        }

    }
private:
    std::ostream &m_os;

};
```

However, when I compile the codes with VC10, the following error appear:

```
 'precison' : is not a member of 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>'
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have VC10 at hands for testing, so I can only make some educated guesses.

`precision()` **is** a member of `std::ostream` (derived from [std::ios_base](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/precision/)),
so the only thing that could have gone wrong is the signature you're using to invoke it:
It expects a `streamsize` and you give it an `int`.

Try [std::setprecision()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/) instead. It takes an `int`.

I think that `std::ios_base::precision(streamsize)` is only for restoring a previously changed value.